# sys.exit() terminates too quickly?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running some code with a sys.exit() call at the end. Without the sys.exit() line, the self.response works just fine and renders the template. But when I call sys.exit(), the page returns blank. It's almost like sys.exit() is interrupting the template mid-render. Why is it doing this?

```
page = 'index.html'
template_values = {}
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), page)
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
sys.exit()
```

**EDIT** I've solved my problem by using "return" instead of "sys.exit()"

Comment: I suspect Python's [internal] buffering is biting the response here -- a flush should do the trick. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering (It would be nice to see an answer on why one approach [say without `sys.exit`] "works" while the other does not; what is the difference in Python termination?)

Comment: You should never call sys.exit on App Engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `sys.exit()`.

If you're basing it on the wording in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Responses **(which has since been reworded)**, pretend for the moment that the use of "exit" in the first two sentences means "completes" or "finishes".

Answer (score 1):

As others have already given good solutions, I'll try to explain why this happens.

The `SystemExit` exception raised by `sys.exit()` differs from other exceptions in one particullar way. If it isn't caught, `sys.excepthook` **isn't** called. Instead, after printing the message contained within it and extracting the exit reason, Python shuts down (`Py_Finalize`) and calls the `ANSI/C` function `exit()` which terminates the process.

A solution is to either let the process end normally (see other answers) or to flush the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can catch `SystemExit` and return normally:

```
def main():
 try:
   ...
 except SystemExit, e:
   # return normally for exit() or exit(0). Otherwise, reraise.
   if e.args and e.args[0]:
     raise
```

Expanding slightly:

The reason it doesn't work is that your Python script isn't being run like a "normal" CGI — there's an exception-catching wrapper, among other things, and sys.exit() is implemented by raising an exception (which doesn't subclass Exception() so it doesn't get caught by default).

I consider this a bug in GAE; you might want to file a bug report. (OTOH, you really shouldn't be using sys.exit() within GAE, since then it's unclear whether your main() function is re-runnable.)

Comment: It's not a bug, because you shouldn't be calling exit from App Engine in the first place.

Comment: @NickJohnson: If it is specifically *App Engine* that causes this failure (i.e. if `if __name__ == "__main__": sys.stdout.write("Status: 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/plain\n\nGoodbye, Cruel World"); sys.exit();` fails), then it is an App Engine bug because App Engine is supposed to give you a CGI-like environment. However, it might actually be a property of the web framework, which would probably not be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the buffer before the sys.exit call:

```
page = 'index.html'
template_values = {}
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), page)
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
self.response.out.flush()
sys.exit()
```